# Standard widget sizes for various screens

Tags: android, widget, size, screen

The widget design guidelines provide the standard widget sizes for your medium sized screen. I'm developing a widget that uses an image background that does not scale well when scaled non-proportionally. So the image resources have been made for the medium sized screen and when testing on different sized screens (large, extra-large, etc.), the widget background doesn't look so good. So I plan on creating different background image resources for each screen size. Is there a way to figure out the standard widget sizes for large, extra-large, or even small screens besides just trial and error? Or am I totally off base here and is there an easier method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android system allows you to place different resources for different density screens. You have to place the different sized resources in their corresponding folders inside the res folder (ie drawable-mdpi vs drawable-ldpi). For more information about creating a UI that runs on multiple screen types see http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.

Comment: Thanks. Also found this helpful tidbit for scaling my resources: there is a 3:4:6:8 scaling ratio between the four densities, so a 9x9 bitmap in ldpi is 12x12 in mdpi, 18x18 in hdpi and 24x24 in xhdpi.